# [Error]: unsupported URL in AWS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, parse-platform

I just exported my parse app to AWS and mLab, but when I go to the server website I get this

[image]

I followed this guide https://www.appcoda.com/parse-server-installation/. All the info on the mLab and AWS were copy and pasted from parse. When I configured the ios app and tried to login to my application I got this error `[Error]: unsupported URL (Code: 100, Version: 1.12.0)`

```
let config = ParseClientConfiguration(block: {
        (ParseMutableClientConfiguration) -> Void in
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.applicationId = "xxxxx";
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.clientKey = "xxxxx";
        ParseMutableClientConfiguration.server = "xxxxx.com/parse/";
    });
Parse.initializeWithConfiguration(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

With the parse-server running if you try `http://localhost:1337` or in your case `xxxxx.com`, you should get a welcome message. If you try `http://localhost:1337/parse` or xxxx.com/parse, you will get the `error: unauthorized` message.

With respect to your other error, your server url should not have a backslash after `parse` i.e. your url should be `xxxxx.com/parse`.

Comment: I get the unauthorized error but when I take the second / away after the /parse I get the same error in the iOS log